# Logcat not giving all the notifications

Tags: xml, android-studio, logcat

I have an app, and I was trying to put ads in it, and I make it run in the emulator, and I noticed that is not giving too much information, only this:

```
01-19 14:35:26.288      404-404/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 138K, 5% free 5592K/5831K, paused 39ms
01-19 14:35:26.318      404-404/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.676MB for 5373424-byte allocation
01-19 14:35:26.398      404-406/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 10838K/11079K, paused 27ms
01-19 14:35:26.458      404-407/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10847K/11079K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-19 14:35:46.268      404-404/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView$LayoutParams.<init>
01-19 14:35:46.268      404-404/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve direct method 9584: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-19 14:35:46.268      404-404/simplemorsecodetranslator.aplicacion.safrapp.simplemorsecodetranslator.segundaparte D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
```

Why isn't giving the full information, even if I press a button or something?, what information do I need to provide?
By the way, my device is in landscape mode, even though it's a phone...

Comment: Do you write anything to the log in your code? Btw. even your phone can be in landscape mode... ;)

Comment: I haven't change the code, It just happened... And for the emulator, I didn't change anything as well.

Comment: Did your code previously generate some more Logcat output? I mean do you log anything at all and are wondering why it is not shown in Logcat?

Comment: I don't log anything, I think...

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any output when a button is pressed unless you explicitly write it to a log. For writing logs you have different logging methods in the Log class:

- v(String, String) (verbose)
- d(String, String) (debug)
- i(String, String) (information)
- w(String, String) (warning)
- e(String, String) (error)

In you button case you could write:

```
Log.i(getClass.getName(), "button pressed");
```

at the appropriate position.

You can check the [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) section in the Android documentation for more information and examples.